# How to disable the infinite scrolling and revert back to normal page?

Tags: catalog

currently using strategery infinite scrolling and my magento is CE 1.8

would like to revert back to normal page scrolling like PAGE 1 of 2

Comment: Not understanding your qst.

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: Am using this extension, but product images not displayed when i scroll down.. @   http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123330/how-can-i-solve-infinite-scroll-down-error

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the extension and how your theme has been modified to work with it. In theory you should be able to disable the module and any templates and layouts it adds would be removed. Its not always that simple though.

Start by editing the module file, in your case it looks like it will be something like app/etc/modules/Strategery_Infinitescroll.xml. Change

```
<active>true</active>
```

to

```
<active>false</active>
```

and clear your cache, this will remove the extension. If your theme has been modifed to rely on the extension it could break things, you should do this in a dev environment to test.

Comment: Am using this extension, but product images not displayed when i scroll down.. @   http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123330/how-can-i-solve-infinite-scroll-down-error